# Getting error while removing package folder

Tags: c#, .net, package, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

[Screen shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtmzp.jpg)
I just removed package folder from my windows form app project for pushing to github, and the source code getting full of errors. All the reference errors are being as it is even if I remove and add the reference again.
Any one knows where I made the mistake?

I tried build and rebuld the solution after removing the package folder.
And I tried to remove and add it again.

But both are not worked, error is still as it is.